# visual Studio 2013: Dll loading error in C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013

I loaded a DLL in C# Visual Studio 2013 for UHF RFID reader. While debugging we faced the following error

> "An unhandled exception of type 'System.DllNotFoundException' occurred
>   in UHFReader188demomain.exe   Additional information: Unable to load
>   DLL 'Basic.dll': The specified module could not be found. (Exception
>   from HRESULT: 0x8007007E)"

Comment: Well where did you expect Basic.dll to come from? What is Basic.dll in this case?

Comment: The answer is in the question. There is a particular code execution path that needs to load the dll basic.dll. check if the dll is present and if it is the correct version.

Comment: For reader,We have two dll's namely Basic.dll  and uhfreader188csharp  when we are trying to load the both dll ... but unable to load the basic.dll file in our program.... basic.dll is the file which include the reader API's. we are not able to load it with the valid assembly for basic.dll

Comment: @shiva r u running your code on execution environment or locally on your machine?

Comment: @Ankur I'm running on my machine

Comment: i think you should run in environment for which it is meant to be ,it wont show error on execution environment.

Comment: Not sure why this is a question at all. It says it can't find a file. Put the file somewhere it can find it.

Comment: Dear Chris, Thanks for your suggestion. Now I am able to load the Basic.dll & its working